# PGconn.connect details of the hash needed in ruby pg gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I would like to better document my code rather than having a statement like the below:

```
pg_c = PGconn.connect("Main-my_db_lk", 5433, '', '', "report_center", "repozenter", "rp_23_xhg")
```

How do I know what is what in this statement? 
Is it possible to point out each parameter to the method like this: port => 5433, host=> xxx

How better write the connection string? what are the empty 3rd and 4th parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to connect in array form are: host, port, options, tty, dbname, user, and password.

The 3rd argument can contain one or more [runtime options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config.html), e.g.,

```
[1] pry(main)> c = PG.connect( '', '', '-c search_path=public,test', '', 'test' )
=> #<PG::Connection:0x007f9e19c16d30>
[2] pry(main)> c.exec( 'show search_path' ).values
=> [["public,test"]]
```

The 4th argument isn't used anymore, but remains for backward-compatibility.

You can also pass a hash of options when connecting, as you suggested, which is a bit clearer:

```
conn = PG.connect( :dbname => 'test', :user => 'postgres' )
```

The available keys are listed in the [API documentation for PG::Connection.new](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-c-new).